# Default position when adding programmatically Images to Grid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to add an image in my grid by clicking a button. I did that but the image is always in the middle of the window.

What should I do to be in top left corner?

Here is my code for xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Grid Name="Grid" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>

        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

And the code for xaml.cs:

```
    static String ImgNameMole = "(project location)/WpfApplication3/Images/Green-icon.png";

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Image Mole = new Image();
        Mole.Width = 15;
        Mole.Height = 15;
        Mole.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        ImageSource MoleImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ImgNameMole));
        Mole.Source = MoleImage;

        Grid.Children.Add(Mole);
    }
```

Comment: Better just bind the `Visibility` property of the `Image` element.

Answer (score 0):

Do what you already did on the Button. Set `HorizontalAlignment` to `Left` and `VerticalAlignment` to `Top` like this:

```
var Mole = new Image();
Mole.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
Mole.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
...
```

Comment: @conflux92 An answer is accepted by clicking the checkmark on the top left side, below the vote count.